# Div border-bottom not displaying

Tags: html, css

I am trying to display a `border-bottom` after each `div`, but only the first `div` is displaying.

```
**My CSS:**

.row:after {
content: " ";
clear:both;
display:block;
}


body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0 solid black;  
    font-family: Verdana,Geneva,sans-serif;
    font-style: normal;
    font-variant: normal;
    font-weight: bold;
}

div.wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    align: center;
    height: auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

*, *:after, *:before {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
}

/***   HEADER   ***/

div.hdr_logo {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  background-color: black;
}

img.hdr_logo {
    position: relative;
    padding: .5em;
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 6em;
}

h3.hdr_logo {
  position: absolute;
  color: #90EE90;
  font-family: Brush Script MT,cursive;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 1em;
   top: 3.75em; 
   left: 5em;
}

div.hdr_links {
  position: absolute;
  width: auto;
  top: .15em;
  right: .5em;
  color: white;
  float: right;
  display: inline;
}

.hdr_links ul{
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.hdr_links li{
    display: inline;
    padding: 0;
}

.hdr_links a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
    font-size: .5em;
    padding: 0;
}

.hdr_links li a:visited {
    color: white;
}

.hdr_links li a:hover {
    color: green;
}

.hdr_links li:not(:first-child):before {
    content: " | ";
}

/***  BANNER   ***/

div.banner {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #101010;
  color: WHITE;
  text-align: center;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;  
}

.banner img{
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 0;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  display: block;
}

.banner h1{
  font-size: 2em;
  padding: .5em;
}

.banner h2{
  font-size: 1.15em;
  padding: .5em;
}

.banner a {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 1em;
  padding: 0;
}

.banner a:link, a:visited {
    background-color: #90EE90;
    color: black;
    padding: 14px 25px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
}

<!--  CAPTION   -->

div.caption {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  display: block;
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
  text-align: left;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;  
}

.caption h3 {
  padding: 1em 0 0 1em;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 1em;
}

.caption a {
  padding: 0 0 0 1em;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 1.25em;
  color: #33CCFF;
}

.caption a:visited {
  color: #33CCFF;
  background-color: white;
}

<!--  CURRENT MONTH  -->

div.currentMonth{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
  border-bottom: 5px solid black;
}

img.currentMonth{
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 0;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  display: block;
}

.currentMonth h1{
    position: relative;
    font-size: 2em;
    text-align: center;
}

.currentMonth h2{
    position: relative;
    font-size: 1.75em;
    text-align: center;
}

.currentMonth a{
    align: left;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #99e6ff;
    background-color: #DEB887;
    padding: .1em .25em .1em .25em;
}

.currentMonth a:hover{
    background-color: #a06d2c;
    color: #99ccff;
}

<!---   FOOTER   --->

div.ftr_main {
    position: relative;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    color: black;
    background-color: white);
  }

h3.ftr_main {
   position: absolute; 
   top: 100px; 
   left: 20px;
   font-size: 14px;
   color: white;
} 

div.ftr_legal {
    position: relative;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    padding: 1em;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    align: center;
    color: white;
    font-size: .75em;
    line-height: 1em;
    background-color: black;
  }

.ftr_legal a{
   align: center;
   font-size: .8em;
   color: white;
   text-decoration: none;
}


**My HTML:**

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1252">
  <meta http-equiv="description" content="<?php echo $page_description; ?>" />
  <title>ZenBox by Jen&trade; ~ <?php echo $page_title; ?></title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ZenBoxStyleNEW.css">
  <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Merienda+One' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'">
</head>

<body>
<div class="wrapper">


<!--  HEADER  -->

<div class="row">
<div class="col-s-12">
  <div class="hdr_logo">
    <a href="index.php"><img class="hdr_logo" src="images/LogoGr150.png"></a>
    <h3 class="hdr_logo">A monthly subscription box of all things Zen.</h3>

    <div class="hdr_links">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="index.php">HOME</a></li>
        <li><a href="ordernow.php">STORE</a></li>
        <li><a href="about.php">ABOUT</a></li>
        <li><a href="whois.php">MEET JEN</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>  <!-- CLOSE DIV HDR_LINKS -->

  </div> <!-- CLOSE DIV HDR_LOGO -->
</div>
</div> <!-- CLOSE ROW  -->
<!--  BANNER  -->

<div class="row">
<div class="col-s-12">
  <div class="banner">

       <h2>
        <?echo $text2text;?><br>
        <?echo $text2L2text;?>
       </h2>
       <h1>
        <?echo $mainText;?><br>
        <?echo $mainText2;?>
       </h1>
       <a href="ordernow.php">BUY NOW</a><br><br><br>

  </div> <!--  CLOSE BANNER  -->
</div>
</div> <!-- CLOSE ROW  -->

<div class="row">
<div class="col-s-12">
  <div class="banner">

    <img src="images/ZenBoxRudys.png">

  </div> <!--  CLOSE BANNER  -->
</div>
</div> <!-- CLOSE ROW  -->



<!--  CAPTION  -->

<div class="row">
<div class="col-s-12">
  <div class="caption">

    <h3><?echo $captionText;?></h3>
    <a href="ordernow.php"><?echo $captionLink;?>&nbsp;&gt;</a>

  </div>
</div>
</div> <!-- CLOSE ROW  -->



<!--  CURRENT MONTH  -->

<div class="row">
<div class="col-s-12">  
  <div class="currentMonth">

    <h1>See What's Inside<br>This Months ZenBox!</h1>
    <img class="currentMonth" src="images/ZenGroupHomepage.jpg">
    <h2>Click <a class="currentMonth" href="ordernow.php">HERE</a> to get started!</h2>
    <br>

  </div> 
</div>
</div>

<!--  FOOTER  -->

<div class="row">
<div class="col-s-12">
  <div class="ftr_legal">
    2016 ZenBox by Jen&trade;  All rights reserved. &nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <a href="terms.php">Terms &amp; Conditions</a><br>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
</div> <!-- CLOSE WRAPPER  -->
</body>
</html>
```

Can someone let me know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: can you please provide markup

Answer (score 1):

We can't figure anything out of this code. Please reproduce the problem with the smallest amount of code possible as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).